# .net viewstate attack from various IP

Tags: .net, c#

I have viewstate logs every seconds :

`https://www.mywebsite.ca/Connexion.aspx?__EVENTVALIDATION=xarOopu5INK8aqufalqvDHhxsADhYKgm6p2eMw8ln83m9Hg/0WyoJZDgkqWQpfJsRRfFdD2qPqx56otYY12w6Lm9+ZczIOYCmBikcJ4I+hpdYQRKniNVLhCWJzo/e3aO+4kXNcPwrZpt6SmzdjHSFks7U3rJwhE5Yh2u+QcdTr8sNygtavOR4PvVc4rgmmwQFv63GAYs6cPwPMe9to22EMamYLnH7F6RYTKAsZfMrSLdamdR2tEkAYrjHOr6DDSyDPlEAELEHfcsE0X4TIbH6knplJ/PPcs94BDzQimWeTEwRDbayhqjNRfMmrpJfAZg+P+zBg==&__VIEWSTATE=pGzxkJJzjeV1FtqBzAVEskpB/ySD2FuZ67cAZkrkfeRXfcV44bS5sVM1Xreuwpl/OwKsQ2R5d0IaDQlrDU5AVOUfQEwz12dG`

User Agent:

```
Mozilla/5.0 (compatible; MSIE 9.0; Windows NT 6.1; WOW64; Trident/6.0)
```

It tries to hit every public page passing various parameters like `__EVENTVALIDATION` or `__VIEWSTATE`.

It's an IP from the United States while our website serves only Canadians. This really looks like an attack but we can't block it by IP because it is always from a new IP.

Any idea how to block them or what this type of attack is called?

Comment: You got me on this one. It will be interesting to see what people can come up with. Cheers!

Comment: Install Fail2Ban, or manually block them using IP Class C.

Answer (score 1):

ASP.NET Event validation does provide some level of protection against some specific web security attacks.

Request Validation, a feature included in ASP.NET 1.1, may not adequately sanitize hostile user-supplied input. ASP scripts that depend on Request Validation to sanitize user-supplied input may still be prone to cross-site scripting or HTML injection attacks as a result. Request Validation may be bypassed by including a null byte (%00) in malicious user-supplied input.

[Microsoft ASP.NET Request Validation Null Byte Filter Bypass Vulnerability](http://www.securityfocus.com/bid/8562/discussion/)

Microsoft has addressed this issue in a Hotfix rollup package and is available by contacting the vendor. Further information can be obtained from this **[link.](http://support.microsoft.com/default.aspx?kbid=821156)**

Comment: Thank you,  At the moment,  we use simple forms that never pass __Eventvalidation as a url parameter.  So at the moment,  if we detect a url that includes this parameter,  we redirect the user to a 404 page.  I think this will do the trick for the moment.